# does adding setTimeout JavaScript/jQuery function help page load quicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does the JavaScript below allow a webpage load quicker opposed to the a standard function or `$(window).load(function(){` OR `$(document).ready()` if not is there a way to allow the page to load then run JavaScript ?

```
setTimeout(function(){
// JavaScript OR jQuery to execute
}, 5000);
```

Comment: put the js at the bottom, there's also the "async" attribute and async loaders, although I belive loaders are snake oil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

`$(document).ready()` Specify a function to execute when the `DOM` is fully loaded.

The function ensures that all html elements (`DOM`) is loaded. So it is not a good idea to use `setTimeout` because you cant know if the browser has built the `DOM` in this time.

You can put your JavaScriptat the end of your document to make sure the browser has built the `DOM` but thats not the way you should do that in case of using jQuery.

#### More Information

`DOM` means Document Object Model

> The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing and interacting with objects in HTML, XHTML and XML documents. Aspects of the DOM (such as its "Elements") may be addressed and manipulated within the syntax of the programming language in use. The public interface of a DOM is specified in its application programming interface (API).

The following functions are the same (overloads) in jQuery.

```
$(function() 
{
  // DOM is loaded
});

$(document).ready(functions() {
  // DOM is loaded
});

// this is the best way if you want prevent collisions with other JavaScript librarys
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // DOM is loaded
});
```

#### - [jQuery Documentation - .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

#### - [Wikipedia - Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: Agree and should have added this to my answer as well.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First, place any JavaScript that is not essential to the construction of the page at the very bottom of the HTML before the closing `</body>` tag.  This includes any script tags that reference external .js files.

Next, if you are using jQuery (and I hope you are), then insert any JS logic you need into this method:

```
$(document)ready(function(){
     //do stuff
});
```

Last, for old school JS, you want to add this to your body tag:

```
onload="YourFunctionName()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing some massive computation with the JS, then no. The majority of your "load" time is spent downloading the assets, not painting/rendering them on the page. If you had any code that sent out other httprequests (ajax), and those fired before the page was finished loading, you'd want to use an onload method somehow. Or just do as clyfe said and put it at the bottom.